# Is max energy level dropping off intentional

Tags: deus-ex-mankind-divided

What was the reasoning behind making the energy bar to 'shrink' when augs are used? I mean it already shrinks from recharge, but occasional power cell puts it back up, however after maxing energy out I realized that my max energy capacity falls down from using augs!

I heavily rely on sneaking up and punching the guys lights out, or going invisible through the lasers, bashing walls,..., and in general I love using augs - IMHO that's what is this game is all about.

**Can I end up in situation where due to max battery 'shrinkage' I can not use augs anymore? What was the reasoning behind this 'feature'? (Or is it a bug?)**

Comment: Can't give a proper answer, but It seems it simulates real batteries. Repeatedly charging them gives less max charge overall, or it at least seems that way

Comment: @BritishFerret Heh, that would be like loosing inventory space because your bag wears out.... 'genius'

Comment: Could be a moral message like "as tech becomes useless now do humans" or something. But it's kind of developer intent so until there's an interview, I doubt we'll get a super clear answer

Comment: I assume the question is about Mankind Divided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, max energy drop-off is intentional, but (a) you cannot get into a situation where you can't use your augs, and (b) it's actually far more forgiving in Mankind Divided than it was in Human Revolution.

(A) Because the max energy bar never drops below the "reserve" portion (the thicker first ~1/4 of the bar), that portion will always recharge.  Also, no augmentation requires more than the reserve portion to function.  So you will always be able to use your augs, but you may have to wait a while to do so.  (There are augs which significantly reduce the wait time.)

(B) Human Revolution was far worse.  When you used certain augs (such as takedown or Typhoon), it removed one cell of energy completely with no chance to auto-recharge it.  In Mankind Divided, most augs behave more like the smart vision system: using the aug does not immediately shift the max energy to the left by the full cost of the aug.  Instead the max bar lags a little (or a lot) to the right of the energy meter, and as long as you don't use another aug right away, you will get most of the energy back.  But if you do use another aug (or continue to use the same one), the max energy will start to fall rather quickly.

Moreover, biocells are **much** more plentiful (and take up **far** less space in your inventory) in MD than in HR.  I spent most of HR with only the reserve energy cell charged, only charging the rest of them when I knew I would need to do multiple takedowns in a row if I wanted to keep my stealth bonus.  In MD I feel like there's almost no penalty for recharging my energy; even if I somehow run out of biocells, I can *make* more!

And the reasoning is to prevent people from spending the entire game with Smart Vision, Titan Armor, and Invisibility turned on, taking down enemies left and right with no challenge whatsoever.  For people who want no challenge, there's the easy mode.  (And the normal mode too. :)

P.S. By the way, the guide pages and the descriptions in the Sarif Series 8 Energy Converter tree explain (i.e. contain technobabble as to) why you lose max energy and why the energy recharge takes time, in case you're looking for an in-universe answer.

Comment: Eh, it's not super technobabble. Basically, the Energy Converter draws energy from the natural chemical reactions produced by the body when breaking down food. As such, using augs is akin to running long distances. If you run long distances non-stop, you'll do a long stretch, then only be able to manage short bursts afterwards. If you take a bite to eat and a nap, you'll recover. Explains why the way to restore energy in HR was eating protein bars, essentially.